# Converting timestamp with timezone to UTC

Tags: java, datetime

I have the following String `"2023-03-21T10:00:51+01:00"`, how can I convert it to UTC time?

My approach is the following

```
final String myDate = "2023-03-021T10:00:51+01:00";
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
Date savedDate = format.parse(myDate);
DateFormat formatterUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatterUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // UTC timezone
String utcDate = formatterUTC.format(savedDate);
```

but I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: Are you sure the day of month `021` can actually be parsed? Or is it just a typo?

Comment: I would encourage you to extract this into a method and write 2-3 unit-tests to validate it and answer your questionst. it can be as simple as `assertThat(formatDateToUTC("2023-03-21T10:00:51-01:00")).isEqualTo("21-03-2023 11:00:51")`

Comment: What is the actual date you are trying to parse?   `2023-03-02` or `2023-03-21`?

Comment: 021 is typo in the example should be 21

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I updated my answer accordingly. Could you please [edit] your question and remove the obsolete zero?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `java.time` instead of `java.util` and `java.text` for parsing and converting, you will be able to do it shorter and more concise:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // examplt input in ISO format
    final String myDate = "2023-03-21T10:00:51+01:00";
    // parse it and get an OffsetDateTime at +01:00
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(myDate);
    // print it
    System.out.println(odt);
    // use the parsed value in order to adjust the offset
    OffsetDateTime utcOdt = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print that, too
    System.out.println(utcOdt);
}
```

Output:

```
2023-03-21T10:00:51+01:00
2023-03-21T09:00:51Z
```

##### Short version:

```
OffsetDateTime utcOdt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-03-21T10:00:51+01:00")
                                      .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

---

###### Edited this question to include OP's comment under his question clarifying the badly formatted input example.

Comment: Yeah, but this will not work with date like this : "2023-03-021T12:00:51+01:00" where the time is 12 it throws wrong format exception

Comment: What is the exact error message? The date with 12 o'clock is invalid because it has three digits "determining" the day of month (same problem as in your question).